# fix Flipcart issue in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

[image]

Hello, according to image I used FlipCard in Flutter and it has back and front option.

it is good work when running it by android emulator, but in web or real host the shadow is visible in browser.

```
    return InkWell(
  hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
  splashColor: Colors.transparent,
  highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
  onTap: () {
    cardKey.currentState!.toggleCard();
  },
  onHover: (bool isHovering) {
    if (isHovering) {
      setState(() {
        isHover = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isHover = false;
      });
    }
  },
  child: FlipCard(
   ....
```